# Is there any package available for scaling to unit length in R?

Tags: r, scaling, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

I want to apply feature scaling technique to my dataset to scale the feature. In particular I want to use scaling to unit length technique to scale my features. I did a bit research on what packages are available for scaling. I did come across these from the internet sources,
[enter link description here][1]

> [1] scale in R - from one of the answers, I got to know that this scaling uses the **Z score normalization technique**.

Is there any package already available to implement scaling to unit length in R? I want to know if there is any package available which implements this formula ,

> X` = X/(||X||).

[1]: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256028/understanding-scale-in-r#:~:text=scale%20%2C%20with%20default%20settings%2C%20will,divide%20by%20the%20std%20deviation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256028/understanding-scale-in-r#:%7E:text=scale%20%2C%20with%20default%20settings%2C%20will,divide%20by%20the%20std%20deviation.))

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
uscale <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
  d <- diff(range(x, na.rm = na.rm))
  (x - min(x, na.rm = na.rm))/d
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do the same by defining a function. Just wanted to check if there are any predefined libraries/packages like scale in R.

Comment: @Luiy_coder asking for package recommendations is off topic here.  This answer shows a good solution in base R.

Comment: Yes the answer is a very good solution and I do agree that!